# Clean URL Re-Writing for PHP at IIS Server

Tags: php, iis, web-config

I am a php developer and I need your help.
I have a website and I want my all cleaned URL come at my index.php file
I have done this in .htaccess but this file is now working in IIS server :(

### What I Wants

If a user hits "xyz.com/1" or "xyz.com/2" then this will call my index.php file under "xyz.com"

Problem is that IIS server show me "/1" or "/2" is not exists.

I want ia a number passed after my URL it will call my index.php 
If passed any string like '/user' or '/manager' this will look into directory.

I listen a file web.config. Even I have tried to configure it but when I upload that file this will generate Internal server error :)

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Show us the web.config you have now. Or take a look at mine web.config. Mine file will always load index.php unless the called file is a existing file or directory. The file and directory exception is for loading javascript/css/image errors. It will send the rest of the url like /user or /manager to script with `$_GET['syst'];`

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="UrlRewrite - DefaultRule">
                   <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                     <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/index.php" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?syst={R:0}" appendQueryString="true"/>
               </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But also: Check if [mod rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is installed on your IIS. Otherwise it would not work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paules,

I have fixed this my self but thanks for this one also :)